# Cannot write to s3 inside EMR getting NPE

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

Anyone seen this before? Dreaded NPE, so have no idea what could be causing it.

Trying to write into s3 via spark `.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet` in an EMR cluster.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.S3Errors.isHttp200WithErrorCode(S3Errors.java:57)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.executor.GlobalS3Executor.execute(GlobalS3Executor.java:100)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.invoke(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:184)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3.lite.AmazonS3LiteClient.deleteObjects(AmazonS3LiteClient.java:127)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.deleteAll(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:364)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.doSingleThreadedBatchDelete(S3NativeFileSystem.java:1380)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.s3n.S3NativeFileSystem.delete(S3NativeFileSystem.java:663)
    at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem.delete(EmrFileSystem.java:337)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.FileCommitProtocol.deleteWithJob(FileCommitProtocol.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.deleteMatchingPartitions(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:223)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:566)
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to AWS it's a known bug and fixed in EMR 5.28.0, so just need to upgrade EMR.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? Thanks!

Comment: Nope, was through an AWS support case.

Answer (score 0):

I would request you to use either s3n:/// or s3a:///. Also make sure in your Spark Session you have these configuration

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .appName(appName)
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.multiobjectdelete.enable","false")
      .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.fast.upload","true")
      .config("spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown", "true")
      .config("spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema", "false")
      .config("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
      .config("spark.speculation", "false")
      .config("fs.s3a.retry.throttle.limit","20")
      .config("fs.s3a.retry.throttle.interval","500ms")
```